# Bootstrap - Align divs differently for various screen resolutions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a total newbie to using Bootstrap and I would like to create what is displayed in the image. This is my starting point.

```
 <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-8'>text</div>
      <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4'>
           <div>text</div>
           <div>
                <div><img src=''/></div>
                <div><img src=''/></div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

[image: Twitter bootstrap div alignment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing here is to understand that if you use a Bootstrap column class, say `.col-md-8`, this will automatically change to a column width of 100% on screen sizes smaller than "md". So, there is no need to add `.col-sm-12` because its automatic.

Please see the Fiddle I created to acocmplish your goal: https://jsfiddle.net/vandigroup/7qLq0tz8/4/

Keep in mind that as mentioned above, on devices smaller than the "sm" breakpoint, column width will change to 100%. You can add an additional `.col-xs-*` to column that you want to control alternatively.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain, much appreciated.